# When two of the same icon is present just one gets displayed

Tags: reactjs

As the title says I have **two icon component that supposed to display the same SVG content, however, when the second gets called, the first disappears.** Not from the DOM, just from the screen...

The case is that I'm **displaying a content card and a modal** filled with corresponding data.
These components are sharing a content object from a separate file. What makes them displaying relevant data is an index prop.

**What I figured out is nothing matters but the two icon component.**

This is how an icon component looks like:
getIcon is a simple switch function returning the icon based on name.
[image]

And this is how I import the SVGs:
[image]

Does anyone can help me with this please? Thanks in advance. No console errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be hoisting.

I had the modal declared first then the content that meant to be clicked to popup the modal.

This makes no sense for me in a component based architecture on the same component level... just wanted to try if always the first icon would disappear or not.